# Link error when installing grako in Python

Tags: cython, grako

I'm trying to install the package grako from PyPI which apparently compiles stuff with Cython. 
I don't know what this process means and it breaks with an unresolved symbol.

Maybe someone can give me a hint what to check for to make this work?

Here is the output on Windows, Anaconda, Python 3.4:

```
Compiling grako\ast.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\bootstrap.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\buffering.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\color.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\contexts.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\diagrams.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\exceptions.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\grammars.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\model.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\parser.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\parsing.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\rendering.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\semantics.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\tool.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\util.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\_version.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\__init__.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\codegen\cgbase.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\codegen\python.py because it changed.
Compiling grako\codegen\__init__.py because it changed.
Cythonizing grako\__init__.py
Cythonizing grako\_version.py
Cythonizing grako\ast.py
Cythonizing grako\bootstrap.py
Cythonizing grako\buffering.py
Cythonizing grako\codegen\__init__.py
Cythonizing grako\codegen\cgbase.py
Cythonizing grako\codegen\python.py
Cythonizing grako\color.py
Cythonizing grako\contexts.py
Cythonizing grako\diagrams.py
Cythonizing grako\exceptions.py
Cythonizing grako\grammars.py
Cythonizing grako\model.py
Cythonizing grako\parser.py
Cythonizing grako\parsing.py
Cythonizing grako\rendering.py
Cythonizing grako\semantics.py
Cythonizing grako\tool.py
Cythonizing grako\util.py
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to grako.egg-info\requires.txt
writing grako.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing entry points to grako.egg-info\entry_points.txt
writing top-level names to grako.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to grako.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'grako.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pdf' found under directory 'etc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'examples\antlr2grako\antlr_parser.py'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'examples\antlr2grako\python.ebnf'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'examples\regex\parser_base.py'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'examples\regex\genparser.py'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.orig' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'grako.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\ast.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\bootstrap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\buffering.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\color.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\contexts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\diagrams.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\grammars.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\model.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\parsing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\rendering.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\semantics.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\tool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
copying grako\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\codegen
copying grako\codegen\cgbase.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\codegen
copying grako\codegen\python.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\codegen
copying grako\codegen\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\codegen
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\test
copying grako\test\ast_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\test
copying grako\test\bootstrap_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\test
copying grako\test\buffering_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\test
copying grako\test\codegen_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\test
copying grako\test\diagram_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\test
copying grako\test\grammar_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\test
copying grako\test\parsing_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\test
copying grako\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\test
copying grako\test\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\test
running build_ext
building 'grako.ast' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\ast.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\ast.obj
ast.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_ast build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\ast.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\ast.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\ast.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\ast.pyd.manifest
ast.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_ast' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\ast.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\ast.exp
building 'grako.bootstrap' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\bootstrap.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\bootstrap.obj
bootstrap.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_bootstrap build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\bootstrap.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\bootstrap.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\bootstrap.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\bootstrap.pyd.manifest
bootstrap.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_bootstrap' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\bootstrap.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\bootstrap.exp
building 'grako.buffering' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\buffering.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\buffering.obj
buffering.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_buffering build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\buffering.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\buffering.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\buffering.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\buffering.pyd.manifest
buffering.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_buffering' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\buffering.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\buffering.exp
building 'grako.color' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\color.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\color.obj
color.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_color build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\color.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\color.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\color.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\color.pyd.manifest
color.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_color' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\color.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\color.exp
building 'grako.contexts' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\contexts.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\contexts.obj
contexts.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_contexts build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\contexts.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\contexts.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\contexts.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\contexts.pyd.manifest
contexts.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_contexts' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\contexts.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\contexts.exp
building 'grako.diagrams' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\diagrams.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\diagrams.obj
diagrams.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_diagrams build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\diagrams.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\diagrams.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\diagrams.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\diagrams.pyd.manifest
diagrams.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_diagrams' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\diagrams.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\diagrams.exp
building 'grako.exceptions' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\exceptions.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\exceptions.obj
exceptions.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_exceptions build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\exceptions.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\exceptions.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\exceptions.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\exceptions.pyd.manifest
exceptions.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_exceptions' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\exceptions.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\exceptions.exp
building 'grako.grammars' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\grammars.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\grammars.obj
grammars.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_grammars build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\grammars.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\grammars.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\grammars.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\grammars.pyd.manifest
grammars.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_grammars' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\grammars.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\grammars.exp
building 'grako.model' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\model.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\model.obj
model.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_model build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\model.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\model.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\model.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\model.pyd.manifest
model.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_model' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\model.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\model.exp
building 'grako.parser' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\parser.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parser.obj
parser.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_parser build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parser.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\parser.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parser.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parser.pyd.manifest
parser.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_parser' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parser.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parser.exp
building 'grako.parsing' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\parsing.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parsing.obj
parsing.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_parsing build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parsing.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\parsing.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parsing.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parsing.pyd.manifest
parsing.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_parsing' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parsing.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\parsing.exp
building 'grako.rendering' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\rendering.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\rendering.obj
rendering.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_rendering build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\rendering.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\rendering.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\rendering.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\rendering.pyd.manifest
rendering.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_rendering' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\rendering.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\rendering.exp
building 'grako.semantics' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\semantics.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\semantics.obj
semantics.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_semantics build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\semantics.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\semantics.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\semantics.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\semantics.pyd.manifest
semantics.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_semantics' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\semantics.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\semantics.exp
building 'grako.tool' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\tool.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\tool.obj
tool.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_tool
build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\tool.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\tool.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\tool.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\tool.pyd.manifest
tool.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_tool' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\tool.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\tool.exp
building 'grako.util' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\util.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\util.obj
util.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_util
build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\util.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\util.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\util.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\util.pyd.manifest
util.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_util' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\util.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\util.exp
building 'grako._version' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\_version.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\_version.obj
_version.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit__version build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\_version.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\_version.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\_version.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\_version.pyd.manifest
_version.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit__version' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\_version.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\_version.exp
building 'grako.__init__' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcgrako\__init__.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\__init__.obj
__init__.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit___init__ build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\__init__.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\__init__.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\__init__.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\__init__.pyd.manifest
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit___init__
build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\__init__.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

It says

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit___init__ build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\__init__.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\grako\__init__.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\__init__.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\__init__.pyd.manifest
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit___init__
build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\grako\__init__.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Is there a simple way I can fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug [52](https://bitbucket.org/apalala/grako/issue/52/) against **Grako**.

Upgrading to version [3.6.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grako/3.6.1) should solve the problem.

Comment: the link to issue tracker is broken, what is the original bug @Generuk

Comment: People should be using [TatSu](https://github.com/neogeny/TatSu) by now. There are still limitations on left-recursive grammars, though.